# GPIO - echo gpioN to export in sysfs I/O error

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

Host: Ubuntu 14.04

Path: `/sys/class/gpio/export`

When I entered the command:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export"
```

The error appeared:

```
sh: echo: I/O error
```

Please advise.

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

Post updated:

dmesg:

```
gpio: Unknown symbol mtd_device_parse_register (err 0)
gpio: Unknown symbol nand_scan (err 0)
gpio: Unknown symbol nand_release (err 0)
```

`export_store invalid GPIO 17`

```
ls -l /sys/class/gpio


  1 total 0
  2 --w------- 1 root root 4096 Dec  9 16:02 export
  3 --w------- 1 root root 4096 Dec  9 16:02 unexport
```

Comment: Look for dmesg output for any errors

Comment: Which GPIO are you trying to utilize in Ubuntu ? what platform is it ?

Comment: What is the board you are using? What is GPIO number? Provide more details, please.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I'm suspecting that N is not a number but a literal N.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko If it so -- it's mistake. Judging from [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt) documentation we can see that only number can be written to the `export`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko, yes, I know, we have to wait for topic starter to elaborate.

Comment: @avd post updated. dmesg shows a lot but only this refers to the GPIO error right after typing the command.

Comment: @SamProtsenko, Andy, N is a number not a literal.

Comment: @stdcall I believe the pin is # 17 and the processor is  Intel Xeon processor D-1540.

Comment: Please report the output from the command `ls -l /sys/class/gpio`

Comment: @sawdust post updated.

Comment: Read [Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt).  There should be some directories for GPIO controllers named **/sys/class/gpio/gpiochipN/**, where N is a number of the base pin.  Seems like your board has no GPIO available through **sysfs**..

Comment: @sawdust yea, but I thought that having gpiochipN is after typing echo output command to the export. However, I might be wrong.

Comment: Try reading the documentation.

Comment: @Sam Actually you are right, that `gpiochipN` directory is being created after you write corresponding number to `export` file. But you are having issue when doing so. You can try to mount debugfs and then see for GPIO configuration like this: `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio`. Otherwise I don't know why you are having that issue, you should look into your CPU manual and also investigate your GPIO driver.

Comment: @SamProtsenko -- You're both confused, and you're providing misleading information. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.emcraft.com/stm32f429discovery/controlling-gpio-from-linux-user-space) that has the **gpiochipN** directory existing prior to `export`ing any pin number.  I have Atmel, Freescale, Marvell and Intel SBCs, and they all have **gpiochipN** directories populated after boot.

Comment: @sawdust Of course there are some directories existing from the start, I'm also seeing them for my board. But not **all** GPIO pins are exported after reboot (at least not in my case, I only can see `gpiochip32`, `gpiochip64`, etc). So if you want to trigger some custom GPIO pin -- you need to export it first. And that's where OP is having the issue.

Comment: @SamProtsenko -- You seem to be confusing ***controller*** entries (which should be there from boot) with ***pin*** entries (which are created when `exported`).

Comment: @sawdust Ah, I see what you mean. OP provided `ls` output and you think that something wrong because there are no existing `gpiochipN` directories there.

Comment: @sawdust I don't confuse them, I know how it works. Just missed the point why it matters in the first place.

Comment: @SamProtsenko *" I don't confuse them, I know how it works."**  --  Really?  Your previous comments clearly indicates the opposite: *"... gpiochipN directory is being created after you write corresponding number to export file."* -- Exporting a (valid) pin creates a **gpioN** directory, not a **gpiochipN** directory (which are generated at kernel initialization).

Comment: @sawdust Ah, right. Just mixed the names, my bad. What I meant, is that in order to manipulate desired GPIO pin, OP **needs** to export it's value first.

Comment: @sawdust Anyway, it has nothing to do with the answer. Seems like the issue is in `gpio_to_desc()` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib-sysfs.c#L435). Probably need to check `ARCH_NR_GPIOS`. Not sure how it works on x86.

Comment: @sawdust Ok, it's porbably 512. So the problem is that GPIO #17 wasn't found in `gpio_to_desc()` function in `list_for_each_entry()` loop. So `gpio_chips` list (in `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c`) wasn't populated. So `gpiochip_add()` wasn't triggered (by GPIO driver probably) **or** GPIO chip just doesn't contain GPIO#17. So next step for OP is to find the actual GPIO driver which is in use for his platform. And figure out, why it's failing to probe or what else is wrong. Maybe errors in dmesg connected to this somehow.